# How do I use the SPLIT function for search on multiple entries in a userform in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, userform

**How the code works right now:** The user can input a single entry, then the code will search in a "RawData" sheet and printing out the corresponding rows containing that specific input to a third "Report" sheet e.g.: *entry12* - This will print out several rows containing that specific entry.

I am trying to add a feature where the user can type in multiple entries in the same textbox and then the code should print out all the respective rows containing those inputs e.g.: *entry12; entry13; entry14*

I thought about using the SPLIT function, but I cannot figure out how to make it work in my existing code.

**The code comes here**

```
Dim opRow As Long

varenNr5 = Trim(Me.txtVaren5.Value)
batchNr5 = VBA.UCase(Me.txtBatch5.Value)
batchNr7 = Trim(Me.txtBatch7.Value)
fremS = Trim(Me.txtFrems.Value)
henS = Trim(Me.txtHens.Value)
antaL = Trim(Me.txtAntal.Value)
varenVan = Trim(Me.txtVarenavn.Value)
If Me.Klinik_JA.Value Then klinkVar = "JA"
If Me.Klinik_NEJ.Value Then klinkVar = "NEJ"
If Me.Klinik_VEDIKKE.Value Then klinkVar = "VED IKKE"

If varenNr5 = "" And batchNr5 = "" And batchNr7 = "" And fremS = "" And henS = "" And antaL = "" And klinkVar = "" Then _
                                        MsgBox "Udfyld minimum ét felt": Exit Sub

Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

With Sheet2

    'Raw Data
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet3.Range("B6:L" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents

    opRow = 6

    For i = 2 To lRow

        '5 varennr (A)
        '5 batchnr (D)
        '7 batchnr (E)
        'Fremstillingsdato (B)
        'Hensantningsdato (C)
        'Antal (G)
        'Varenvan (F)
        'Klink (JA, NEJ, VED IKKE) (H)

        If varenNr5 <> "" And varenNr5 <> Trim(.Range("A" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If batchNr5 <> "" And batchNr5 <> Trim(.Range("D" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If batchNr7 <> "" And batchNr7 <> Trim(.Range("E" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If fremS <> "" And fremS <> Trim(.Range("B" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If henS <> "" And henS <> Trim(.Range("C" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If antaL <> "" And antaL <> Trim(.Range("G" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If varenVan <> "" And varenVan <> Trim(.Range("F" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls
        If klinkVar <> "" And klinkVar <> Trim(.Range("H" & i)) Then GoTo nextRowPls

        Sheet3.Range("B" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("A" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("C" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("B" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("D" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("C" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("E" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("D" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("F" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("E" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("G" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("F" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("J" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("G" & i)
        Sheet3.Range("K" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("H" & i)
        'Sheet3.Range("L" & opRow) = Sheet2.Range("I" & i)

        opRow = opRow + 1
nextRowPls:
    Next i

End With

Sheet3.Activate
'MsgBox "Udskrivning fuldført. " & opRow - 6 & " resultater fundet."
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub txtVaren5_AfterUpdate()

    If Trim(Me.txtVaren5.Value) <> "" Then

        Dim aCell As Range


        Set aCell = Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).Find(What:=Trim(Me.txtVaren5.Value), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then Me.txtVarenavn.Value = Sheet2.Range("F" & aCell.Row)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Ryd_Indskrivning_Click()
'Nulstiller felter indeholdende tekst
'----------------------------------------------------------------
Me.txtVaren5.Value = ""
Me.txtBatch5.Value = ""
Me.txtBatch7.Value = ""
Me.txtFrems.Value = ""
Me.txtHens.Value = ""
Me.txtAntal.Value = ""
Me.txtVarenavn.Value = ""

'Nulstiller Klinik knapper
'----------------------------------------------------------------
Me.Klinik_JA.Value = False
Me.Klinik_NEJ.Value = False
Me.Klinik_VEDIKKE.Value = False
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
txtBatch5.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Split your text into an array and add an extra loop to go through each element of the array. `Split` produces the array.

Comment: Generally advised also to avoid `Goto` by restructuring your code.

Comment: @SJR Can you show me an example please?

Comment: An example of using split or restructuring the code? (The latter is not really the meat of your question so would put that aside for the moment.) I suggest you read [mcve] as I cannot provide a meaningful answer to your question as I don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Which input did you want to be able to Split?

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation, I will try to clarify my question. 
As it is now, it is only possible to input one single "5 batchnr" in the userform, which then prints the corresponding row(s) containing that "5 batchnr". 

What I am trying to do is to somehow be able to input multiple inputs separated by ";" which then prints the rows containing those inputs. 

I have read extensively on the VBA function: SPLIT, and it seems like that could be my solution, but I cannot introduce the function in code code and make it work.